# Boostrap dropdown menu only working on parent page

Tags: navigation, theming

I have a question, which I want to solve for a really long time now.
I'm creating my own boostrap sub-theme.

I 3 links in my drupal menu:
[image]

I want this menu to be available on every page, and it should be possible to access every link on every page. My code in page.tpl.php:

```
<div class="<?php print $navbar_classes ?>">
    <div class="container">
        <?php if (!empty($primary_nav) || !empty($secondary_nav) || !empty($page['navigation'])): ?>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <nav role="navigation">
                    <?php print render($primary_nav) ?>
                    <?php print render($secondary_nav) ?>
                    <?php print render($page['navigation']) ?>
                </nav>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

However I can only go to the sub (e.g. /info/sub) when I'm on  the parent (e.g. info). I have tried to use superfirsh but then I loose all advantages of boostrap.

Home page, there isn't a caret:

[image]

Info page, there is a caret:

[image]

Note that the HTML code for the dropdown menu isn't available on the home page.

I know this is possible, but how? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you please try this:

1. Go to structure and then open your menu link
2. Enabled the "Show as expanded" option for your parent menu item.(in your case it is info menu item).

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks this worked. I found that option, but though it meant something different.

Comment: Was looking for this so long.